# env: ‘go’: No such file or directory make: *** [Makefile:43: build] Error 127?

Tags: go, go-ethereum

https://github.com/ChainSafe/ChainBridge

Why does this command not work?

```
make build
```

I cloned the repo locally, cd'd into the right folder; all I get back in the Git CLI is

```
  >  \033[32mBuilding binary...\033[0m
cd cmd/chainbridge && env GOARCH=amd64 go build -o ../../build/chainbridge -ldflags="-X main.Version=v.1.1.2-2-g6f55404"
env: ‘go’: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:43: build] Error 127
```

I downloaded Go for Windows 10 64 bit, version 1.16.4

Answer (score 0):

With Go, you don't really need to use Makefiles anymore. I think people just do it out of habit. I don't agree with the practice, as Go is a new language, and I don't like to see people misuse it by continuing to work with old crappy tools from the past. To that end, you can just download the code, then change location to:

```
cmd\chainbridge
```

Then run:

```
go build
```

I know this works, as I just did it with `go version go1.16.3 windows/amd64`. Also, you need to make sure `go.exe` is on your `PATH`. You probably need to add `C:\go\bin` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error in ubuntu
this help me to resolve this

In terminal type

```
which go
```

you will get the full path like

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

Add this to make file

```
GOFULLPATH := /usr/local/go/bin/go



build:
     $(GOFULLPATH) build -o name main.go
```